# Regular expression matching issue with the following scenario

Tags: java, regex

I am developing an application. User will enter some of the setting value in the server. When I ask for the value to the server through the inbuilt API. I am getting values like as a whole string:
for example-

```
name={abc};display={xyz};addressname={123}
```

Here the properties are name, display and address and there respective values are abc, xyz and 123.
I used to split with ; as first delimeter and = as a second dleimeter.

```
String[] propertyValues=iPropertiesStrings.split(";");
        for(int i=0;i<propertyValues.length;i++)
        {
            if(isNullEmpty(propertyValues[i]))
                continue;

            String[] propertyValue=propertyValues[i].split("=");
            if(propertyValue.length!=2)
                mPropertyValues.put(propertyValue[0], "");
            else
                mPropertyValues.put(propertyValue[0], propertyValue[1]);
        }
    }
```

here mPropertyValues is hash map which is used for keeping property name and its value.

Problem is there can be string :

```
case 1:  name={abc};display={ xyz=deno; demo2=pol };addressname={123}
case 2:  name=;display={ xyz=deno; demo2=pol };addressname={123}
```

I want hashmap to be filled with :

case 1:

```
name ="abc" 
display = "xyz= demo; demo2 =pol"
addressname = "123"
```

for case 2:

```
name =""
display = "xyz= demo; demo2 =pol"
addressname = "123"
```

I am looking for a regular expression to split these strings;

Comment: Can a set of braces include nested braces? As in `name={ abc={x};xyz={12} }`?  If so then the grammar is recursive and not a good candidate for regex parsing.  You'd need to write a state-machine or recursive descent parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that there can't be nested `{}` this should do what you need

```
String data = "name=;display={ xyz=deno; demo2=pol };addressname={123}";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<name>\\w+)=(\\{(?<value>[^}]*)\\})?(;|$)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(data);

while (m.find()){
    System.out.println(m.group("name")+"->"+(m.group("value")==null?"":m.group("value").trim()));
}
```

Output:

```
name->
display->xyz=deno; demo2=pol
addressname->123
```

Explanation

`(?<name>\\w+)=(\\{(?<value>[^}]*)\\})?(;|$)` can be split into parts where

- `(?<name>\\w+)=` represents XXXX= and place `XXXX` in group named `name` (of property)
- `(\\{(?<value>[^}]*)\\})?` is optional `{XXXX}` part where `X` can't be `}`. Also it will place `XXXX` part in group named `value`.
- `(;|$)` represents `;` OR end of data (represented by `$` anchor) since formula is `name=value;` or in case of pair placed at the end of data `name=value`.

Answer (score 0):

The following regex should match your criteria, and uses named capturing groups to get the three values you need.

```
name=\{(?<name>[^}])\};display=\{(?<display>[^}]+)\};addressname=\{(?<address>[^}]\)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your dataset can change, a better parser may be more dynamic, building a `Map` from whatever is found in that return type.

The regex for this is pretty simple, given the cases you list above (and no nesting of `{}`, as others have mentioned):

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(\\w+)=(?:\\{(.*?)\\})?").matcher(source_string);
while (m.find()) {
    if (m.groupCount() > 1) {
        hashMap.put(m.group(1), m.group(2));
    }
}
```

There are, however, considerations to this:

1. If m.group(2) does not exist, "null" will be the value, (you can adjust that to be what you want with a tiny amount of logic).
2. This will account for varying data-sets - in case your data in the future changes.

What that regex does:

1. `(\\w+)` - This looks for one or more word characters in a row (A-z_) and puts them into a "capture group" (`group(1)`)
2. `=` - The literal equals
3. `(?:...)?`  - This makes the grouping not a capture group (will not be a `.group(n)`, and the trailing `?` makes it an optional grouping.
4. `\\{(.*?)\\}` - This looks for anything between the literals `{` and `}` (note: if a stray `}` is in there, this will break).  If this section exists, the contents between `{}` will be in the second "capture group" (`.group(2)`).